# R (GLM) Split continuous variate with missing values into variate and a factor for missing values

Tags: r, glm, missing-data

I was wondering if anyone knew if there was a way to take a continuous variate with missing values into a continuous variate and a factor for the missing level. Essentially I want the GLM to fit me the variable without taking the NAs into account and just fit a separate parameter for the NA level.

I tried doing this using interactions but of course this introduces an alias into the model.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to understand your question if you included a simple example code of what you are trying to accomplish.
From what I understand, you want to break the effect of one variable into two different variables: one for the valid data and one for the NAs.

However, usually dropping NAs means giving up the whole observation (row). So you wouldn't be able to use the *remaining* information for that observation (so there will be no point in adding information about the presence of NAs to the observation. It will be discarded anyway)

Now I don't know about the specifics of your data and application, but if you insist on introducing a new parameter to indicate rows having NAs, what you could do is to [impute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imputation_(statistics)) the missing values, and then add your "NAs parameter". This way you would keep all the observations and still provide the model with additional information about the presence of missing values.
Then again, if you actually to the imputation, you should also ask if the "NAs parameter" is still justified; again, depends on your specific problem.

But doing imputation is a sensitive design decision. You should be careful about introducing additional information into your data. The same can be said about the "NA parameter", unless you know the underlying reason for the missing values\.